# implement an interface with a private method in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, interface

I was kind of shocked by this. Could someone explain why this works? A good example of when to use it would also be nice.

```
Public Interface IFoo
  Sub DoIt()
End Interface

Public Class Bar
  Implements IFoo

  Private DoIt() implements IFoo.DoIt
End Class

...

Dim b as new Bar()
b.DoIt() 'error
CType(b, IFoo).DoIt() 'no error
```

Comment: So that code works? I'm surprised. Seems very contrary to the idea of an interface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having a private interface implementation basically just allows you to implement an interface without having to muddy your class' API.  You can implement `IFoo`, but only APIs that treat you as an `IFoo` need to know that.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b3c4by9.aspx) says

> You can use a private member to implement an interface member. When a private member implements a member of an interface, that member becomes available by way of the interface even though it is not available directly on object variables for the class.

Answer (score 6):

> I was kind of shocked by this. Could someone explain why this works? A good example of when to use it would also be nice.

This concept is pretty much analogous to C#'s explicit interface implementation. There, too, you can only access the interface's member if you cast the type explicitly to that interface.

I can't comment on *why* the .NET framework team felt this feature was really necessary though. It might sometimes strengthen encapsulation but I'm not sure of this. In any case, something extremely similar would always be possible using composition instead of (interface) inheritance.

Comment: When the member is "private", it serves the same purpose as C#'s explicit interface implementation, and has basically the same semantics (a C# explicit would be equivalent to a vb-style private implementation with a unique random private name).  The big benefit to vb's approach comes when implementing interfaces with `Protected Overridable` functions.  Derived classes can then implement the interface in terms of the parent's implementation, something which is not possible in C# without adding an extraneous level of indirection.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the question was covered in other posts, but I didn't see an example. I commonly use this when implementing generic interfaces and their non-generic counterparts. For example, if I want to make a generic ObservableList, I would want to implement both IList interfaces.

```
Public Class ObservableList(Of T)
    Implements INotifyCollectionChanged, 
               IList, 
               IList(Of T)
End Class
```

When both ILists are implemented we end up with a lot of duplicate functions. Some share the same signature and can implement both IList functions like Clear. But some of the non-generic functions deal with objects instead of the generic. So for the Add function, I would make both implementations work, but set the non-generic version private to make using the class easier.

```
Public Sub Add(item As T) Implements System.Collections.Generic.ICollection(Of T).Add
    'Add item to collection
End Sub

Private Function Add1(item As Object) As Integer Implements System.Collections.IList.Add
    'Add item to collection
End Function
```

This way, the class can be passed and used as an IList, but a coder gets to use it as an IList(Of T) without the potential overload clutter.