# why can't my nhibernate equals method find my fields?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

so I have this (VB, sorry) object:

```
Class Foo

  Private ReadOnly foo as Integer

  Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Foo() as Integer
    Get
      Return foo
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Overridable Overloads Function Equals(ByVal other as Foo) as Boolean
    Return Me.foo.Equals(other.foo)
  End Function

  Public Overloads Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj as Object) as Boolean
    ... some boilerplate ...
    Return Equals(DirectCast(obj, Foo))
  End Function
End Class
```

the big mystery is, when I load an object from the database, in `Equals()`, `other.foo` is always zero, even though the value in `Foo()` is correct.

how could this be?

Another version of the Equals method was this:

```
Private Overloads Function Equals(ByVal other as Foo) as Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of Foo).Equals
  Return Me.foo.Equals(other.foo)
End Function
```

And in this version, **both** `Me.foo` and `other.foo` are zero.

Answer (score 0):

several hours later, i discovered that the object-type Equals() method was the culprit, presumably because the DirectCast-ed instance bypassed the proxy.

In the second instance, the problem was that the private implementation ([of an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436305/implement-an-interface-with-a-private-method-in-vb-net)!  who knew!) was bypassing the proxy.

So, the moral of the story appears to be: **avoid DirectCast,** and **avoid private interface implementation.**  :-)

Comment: Seems like maybe the best practice is to not use fields at all, at least not in Equals().  http://blog.xebia.com/2008/03/08/advanced-hibernate-proxy-pitfalls/